# How to convert blank/cells that have hidden characters to nulls or otherwise remove hidden characters

Tags: sql, excel, database, ssis

I am loading data from Excel to SQL database using SSIS package.  My SSIS package is fail due to there are some hidden characters in empty cells so I need to replace those empty cells to nulls or remove/delete hidden characters. My excel columns are formatted to "numbers". Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What kind of hidden characters do you have?  Are they consistent?  A sample of the problematic data would be helpful.

Comment: Dear Alexherm
Thank you very much for trying to help me; currently I have a SSIS Package to load data from Excel spreadsheet to SQL Database. I have to process around 25-30 spreadsheets every day. I receive those spreadsheets from different people and some of them failed to load data. Those excel files have blank cells/columns and when I manually delete the content of blank cells, file will work which means there are some hidden characters on those blank cells. I am not very sure which type of hidden characters are they.

Comment: So configure the package to perform the same task you are doing manually.  Or load the data into a staging table that will not fail the special characters (maybe make the columns char instead of number), and then create a routine that cleans the records and then loads into master table

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have unnecessary spaces in your data. I'd switch the formatting to "general" and then use the TRIM function if the  data is already separated by cells. If it's the entire cells that need to be deleted, I'd click "Go to Special" under find a select, select blanks, and then delete them. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asciitable.com/

Combination of ASCII characters forms a string in any relational database.
For example : NULL is assigned as ASCII character 0.
If there is CHAR(0) in front up any string value then that value will not be visible to the human eye.
As the same way there are many hidden characters which is not visible.
We can still remove those hidden characters from

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CleanupData2] 
(
       @nstring nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN

       DECLARE @Result varchar(255)
       SET @Result = ''

       DECLARE @nchar nvarchar(1)
       DECLARE @position int
       SET @position = 1
       
       WHILE @position <= LEN(@nstring)
        BEGIN
            SET @nchar = SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1)
        IF((ASCII(@nchar) BETWEEN 64 and 90) OR (ASCII(@nchar) BETWEEN 97 and 122) OR (ASCII(@nchar) BETWEEN 48 and 57) OR ASCII(@nchar) = 32)
             BEGIN
                    SET @Result = @Result + @nchar
             END
         ELSE 
            BEGIN
             DECLARE @asciichar varchar(10)
             SET @asciichar = ASCII(@nchar)
             SET @Result = @Result + REPLACE(@nchar,CHAR(@asciichar),'')
           END
       SET @position = @position + 1
   END

RETURN @Result

END

GO
```